# ZXing, can't get code. 

Tags: android, android-activity, zxing

I'm working on an application that calls the `ZXing` scanner on button click. That works fine, after scanning the code a new activity pops up which should get the scanned code, so I could edit it put in an amount how much I want from that product, etc. But I don't know how to get that scanned code. Here is what I have so far:

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     // Set up click listeners for all the buttons

        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View editButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scan_button:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        break;
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent about = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),About.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putString("key","blablabla");


            about.putExtras(b);
            startActivityForResult(about, 0);
        break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();
        break;


                    }
                }



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                // Handle successful scan
                Intent result = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Result.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putString("contents",contents);


                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivityForResult(result, 0);



            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the called activity named Result

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Result extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        View finishButton =findViewById(R.id.finish_button);
        finishButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View nextButton =findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();


        String product = b.getString("contens").toString();

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        et1.setText(product);



        }
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.finish_button:
                finish();
            break;
            case R.id.next_button:
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                finish();
            break;

            }
        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                    // Handle successful scan
                    Intent result = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Result.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("contents",contents);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivityForResult(result, 0);

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle cancel
                }
            }
        }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use their integration JAR. It provides code to handle everything you are trying to do above. You can see the source code for `IntentIntegrator` [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java), and here is [a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/zxingdemo) demonstrating its use.

Comment: Thank you, but i dont really understand what that project  is doing, and you dont know maybe why my code isnt working, is there something with the format of the scanned code? Its not a string?

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of result, i wrote intent, but now it works just well,my way. Without any lib. Thank you for your cooperation. Answer accepted.